# How to get rotation.y from 1 object and apply it to another

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I have a door obj and a glass obj and I place my door open/close script on my door obj and i want to take the rotation each update of the door and apply it to the glass obj. I created this script for the door and then i want to apply the `rotatePositionY` on my other obj.

```
public float rotatePositionY;

void Update () {

    rotatePositionY = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

}
```

on the other obj i created this script but i am not use how to tell unity to assist the `doorRotateExport` correct, i get an error using `transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y`. I think it only works for getting the float not for assign another float. Which is the correct way to do that?

```
public DoorRotateExport doorRotateExport;


void Start () {

    doorRotateExport = GameObject.Find ("doorgim").GetComponent<DoorRotateExport> ();
}


void Update () {

    transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y = doorRotateExport;
}
```

Comment: Put the glass object inside the door in the inspector. This way when you move the door all the hierarchy will behave in the same way.

Comment: ^ Yes it works only in appropriate situations. But in OP it only requires `y` component of rotation. So this wont be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for your second obj:

```
    public DoorRotateExport doorRotateExport;

    void Start () {
        doorRotateExport = GameObject.Find("doorgim").GetComponent();
    }

    void Update () {
        Vector3 newAngle = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        newAngle = doorRotateExport.rotatePosistionY;
        transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y = newAngle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a variable of type `DoorRotateExport` to a `float` value.

Fix this by changing this line on the script of the second object

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y = doorRotateExport;
```

to this:

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y = doorRotateExport.rotatePosistionY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't suggest updating rotation like this but If there is no other workaround and you have to assign it in `update()` method then here is a piece of working code:

```
public DoorRotateExport doorRotateExport;

void Start () 
{
    doorRotateExport = GameObject.Find ("doorgim").GetComponent<DoorRotateExport> ();
}

void Update () 
{

    Quaternion _rotation =  transform.rotation;
    _rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotation.eulerAngles.x,doorRotateExport.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,_rotation.eulerAngles.z);
    transform.rotation = _rotation;
}
```